# Парсинг строки в Java в HashMap

Tags: java

Как правильнее распарсить строку.
Строка вот такого типа: `key:value|key:value|key:value`

В итоге планирую получить `HashMap<String, Integer>`. 
Пример: "Temperature:35"

Comment: Что уже делали вы? Желательно оформить кодом в вопрос. Какие ошибки или недопонимания возникли? Нужно больше подробностей.

Comment: @And А какая у вас у вас проблема? Пишите, я вам попробую помочь.

Comment: @Astar75 5 балов за ваш последний комментарий =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) split:

```
   String example = "Terminator:35|SuperMen:53|Robbin:12";
   String[] pairs = example.split("\\|");
   Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
   for (String pair : pairs) {
      String[] keyValue = pair.split(":");
      map.put(keyValue[0], Integer.valueOf(keyValue[1]));
   }
```

2) regex:

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    String example = "Terminator:35|SuperMen:53|Robbin:12";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+):(\\d+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(example);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        map.put(matcher.group(1), Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(2)));
    }
    System.out.println(map);
```

3) в цикле, не сильно оптимально вышло, но

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    String example = "Terminator:35|SuperMen:53|Robbin:12";

    StringBuilder key = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();
    boolean keyFlag = true;
    boolean valueFlag = false;
    for (char ch : example.toCharArray()) {
        if (ch == ':') {
            valueFlag = true;
            keyFlag = false;
        } else if (ch == '|') {
            keyFlag = true;
            valueFlag = false;
            map.put(key.toString(), Integer.valueOf(value.toString()));
            value = new StringBuilder();
            key = new StringBuilder();
        } else {
            if (keyFlag) {
                key.append(ch);
            } else if (valueFlag) {
                value.append(ch);
            }
        }
    }
    map.put(key.toString(), Integer.valueOf(value.toString()));
    System.out.println(map);
```